# How to use the Assert in a block?

Tags: ios, asynchronous, block, assert, gh-unit

I had questions about how to use the Assert in a block?

For example:

```
[someObject postRequestWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

    CFRunLoopRef runLoopRef = CFRunLoopGetCurrent();
    CFRunLoopStop(runLoopRef);

    GHAssertTrue(succeeded&&!error, @"faile");

}];
CFRunLoopRun();
```

It will have to send an asynchronous request .
After it is completed, I need to Assert whether it is successful.

But it's going to crash!

How i should do?

thx!

PS:
- (void)testCase
{
    [self prepare];

```
__block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];

__block typeof (&*self) bself = self;

[request setCompletionBlock:^{

    [bself notify:kGHUnitWaitStatusSuccess forSelector:@selector(testCase)];
    GHAssertTrue(YES, @"faile");
}];

[request setFailedBlock:^{

    [bself notify:kGHUnitWaitStatusFailure forSelector:@selector(testCase)];
    GHAssertTrue(NO, @"faile");
}];

[request startAsynchronous];

[self waitForStatus:kGHUnitWaitStatusCancelled timeout:15.0];
```

}

Comment: Wouldn't you want to assert that completion was false and the error was true? You have them the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [async section of the docs](http://gh-unit.github.io/gh-unit/docs/appledoc_include/guide_testing.html) (mainly the bit under `ExampleAsyncTest.m:`). Something like:

```
-(void)testCase
{
    [someObject postRequestWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

        [self notify:succeeded ? kGHUnitWaitStatusSuccess : kGHUnitWaitStatusFailure forSelector:@selector(testCase)];

        GHAssertTrue(succeeded&&!error, @"faile");

    }];

    [self waitForStatus:kGHUnitWaitStatusSuccess timeout:10.0];    
}
```

I would recommend the [Expecta](https://github.com/specta/expecta) testing framework too, its got a nice clean syntax.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!! 
But I'm still here, there is a problem.
if the Assert in this block, it's going to crash.
My block is the problem?